# Acceleration of Simple pendulum

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

A simple pendulum starts its motion from one extreme when it left at extreme it starts its motion towards the extreme and its velocity become increase and become maximum at mean position and also acceleration will increase by increasing of velocity and after passing from mean position velocity of pendulum will decrease and also acceleration will negative and at this satuation my question is that what will its accelration at mean position?
But i think it will be zero and also will be zero at both extremes because i think at the mean position its the point from what the bob's velocity become decrease and accceleration become negative at decreasing of velocity and before retardation or negative accelration it will come a point at what the accelration of bob will be zero and then become negative

Comment: The wikipedia graphic for a pendulum includes velocity and acceleration vectors. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Oscillating_pendulum.gif

Comment: I think some sentence structure is needed here (e.g., actual sentences, rather than the run-ons present).

Comment: This question would benefit from some careful editing. It is really very hard to understand what you are asking. That said, if I understand the question as written, John Rennie's answer is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you're talking about an ideal pendulum or a real pendulum.

For an ideal pendulum we can ignore the up and down motion of the bob and consider only sideways motion. In that case the equation of motion is:

$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\frac{g}{\ell}x \tag{1} $$

where $x$ is the displacement of the pendulum bob, $\ell$ is the length of the cord and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity. At the middle point $x = 0$ and therefore equation (1) tells us that the acceleration $d^2x/dt^2$ is zero. So you are correct that the acceleration is zero at the centre point.

A real pendulum moves in a circular arc, so at the middle point there is a radial acceleration given by:

$$ a_r = \frac{v^2}{\ell} $$

where $v$ is the velocity of the bob.

Answer (score 0):

It is never zero until it stops at the mean point. Try not to think of were it is, but were it is going. It may seem "stopped", but it is just accelerating in the other direction. Velocity at the extremes, however, is zero.

Comment: Hmm... someone commented then deleted

Comment: That was me. I was going to say the OP was probably thinking about an ideal pendulum, but I decided to post an answer instead. As a general comment, I think a good answer doesn't just give the answer but it explains why. My answer is essentially the same as yours but with the equations added to show **why** the acceleration of a real pendulum is not zero at the centre point.